# SQL query assign days to periods based on end date

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have a table that has a list of dates from now till 2015.
eg.

```
Date
11/1/2013
12/1/2013
13/1/2013
...
25/1/2013
```

I have a separate table this holds report dates.

```
cutoff_ date    purpose
11/1/2013       Mid Month Report
25/1/2013       Month End Report
```

So I need to assign a the dates between 11/1/2013 and 25/1/2013 all to 25/1/2013 whats the best way to go about this?

Can I do it in a simple SQL query? 
The DB is currently in Access if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DMin` to retrieve the minimum *cutoff_date* which is greater than or equal to *[Date]*.

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    DMin("cutoff_date", "report_dates",
        "[cutoff_date] >= " & Format([Date], "\#yyyy-m-d\#")) AS report_date
FROM first_table;
```

Comment: Sorry, that was missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Hi HansUp, the Format([Date] should be Format([cutoff_date] that was screwing it up too. Cheers

Comment: oh and I used "dd-mm-yyyy" what does \# do?

Comment: A `#` in a format pattern is a "digit placeholder".  But I wanted `Format()` to include the actual `#` characters in its output string as date delimiters.  The backslash signals `Format()` to ignore the following character's usual format meaning, and just include the literal character instead.

Comment: Oh I need to use SELECT DISTINCT otherwise I got duplicate entries.

Comment: So I used: SELECT DISTINCT Dates.Day, DMin("cutoff_date","Reporting_Dates","[cutoff_date] >= " & Format([Day],"\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")) AS report_date
FROM Dates, Reporting_Dates;

Answer (score 0):

There can be advantages to using subqueries, for example, you can use a parameter, which can be assigned in code, got from a form, or simply typed in. This example selects only those records that have a date that matches the cutoff_date purpose entered in the prompt `[please enter purpose]`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dates.day,
                (SELECT TOP 1 cutoff_date
                 FROM   report_dates
                 WHERE  cutoff_date >= dates.day
                        AND purpose = [please enter purpose]
                 ORDER  BY cutoff_date) AS CutOff
FROM   dates
WHERE  (SELECT TOP 1 cutoff_date
        FROM   report_dates
        WHERE  cutoff_date >= dates.day
               AND purpose = [please enter purpose]
        ORDER  BY cutoff_date) IS NOT NULL;
```